# bash help - script to run a command for folders matching a pattern

Tags: bash, kubectl

I'm wanting to create a script which can run `k apply -Rf ./service-token-auth` for each of the logical groups here. Mainly all of the graphql-* and data-service-* folders.

Is this something that would be quite easy to implement?

```
$ ls
README.md                       data-service-notifications      orchestration-workflows-service
argo-cd                         data-service-reports            postgresql-operator
argocd                          data-service-user               prometheus
azure-identities                diagnostic-tools                pushgateway
azure-nginx-ingress             gloo-gateway                    reloader
azure-private-dns               graphql-gateway                 service-auth
azure-rbacs                     graphql-service-applications    service-b2c-gateway
azure-secrets                   graphql-service-clients         service-dast-auth
blackbox-exporter               graphql-service-findings        service-dast-ml
cadence                         graphql-service-logging         service-mesh
data-service-application        graphql-service-user            service-token-auth
data-service-clients            kube-state-metrics              strimzi-kafka
data-service-findings           kuberhealthy                    tartarus
data-service-logging            kubernetes-reflector            whs-opa
```

Comment: Do you want to go into those folders and run the script?

Comment: no sorry, I want to run the command with each folder a parameter. I want a script that will execute:

k apply -Rf ./graphql-service-applications
k apply -Rf ./graphql-service-clients

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate over files in bash

first make sure that it only hits the folders that you want

```
for i in graphql-* data-service-*; do echo $i; done
```

then execute

```
for i in graphql-* data-service-*; do k apply -Rf ./$i; done
```